# image src not loaded when using scheme-less URI

Tags: html, apache, nginx, https, http-status-code-404

The img is not loaded in :

https://my_nginx_hosted_site_using_SSL/page_containing_img_from_external_source

when replacing

```
 <img src=" http://my_apache_hosted_site_noSSL/files/public/penguins.jpg" >
```

by

```
 <img src="//my_apache_hosted_site_noSSL/files/public/penguins.jpg" >
```

Is it not supposed to work fine ?
What can be the reason why it is not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheme-less URLs use http when called from a http site, and https when called from a https site. That's the point of it. They are not "scheme-less really, you just don't specify the scheme on the page and the browser fills it in as appropriate.

You're server is called my_apache_hosted_site_noSSL in your question so I'm guessing from that name it is not available over https!

Also as the image is not available over https you will not be able to show it on a https page without getting mixed content errors. If you thought using a scheme-less URL was going to protect you from that then you are completely mistaken in your understanding of what scheme-less URLs are and how mixed content works.